# Kotlin - when expression over class type

Tags: kotlin

I'm attempting to write an invocation handler that uses a map (supplied at runtime) to implement an interface's getters.

This very crudely works. I know the basic types that may be returned, so I'm OK with having a when expression.

I haven't found a way to avoid using the name of the class as the subject of the when expression; is there a better way?

```
class DynamicInvocationHandler<T>(private val delegate: Map<String, Any>, clzz: Class<T>) : InvocationHandler {

    val introspector = Introspector.getBeanInfo(clzz)
    val getters = introspector.propertyDescriptors.map { it.readMethod }

    override fun invoke(proxy: Any, method: Method, args: Array<Any>?): Any? {
        if (method in getters) {
            // get the value from the map
            val representation = delegate[method.name.substring(3).toLowerCase()]
            // TODO need better than name
            when (method.returnType.kotlin.simpleName) {                
                LocalDate::class.simpleName -> {
                    val result = representation as ArrayList<Int>
                    return LocalDate.of(result[0], result[1], result[2])
                }
                // TODO a few other basic types like LocalDateTime
                // primitives come as they are
                else -> return representation
            }
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`when` expressions support any type (unlike Java's `switch`), so you can just use the `KClass` instance itself:

```
when (method.returnType.kotlin) {                
    LocalDate::class -> {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use the types instead of the class names in the `when` statement. After a type is matched, Kotlin smart cast will automatically cast it

**Example**

```
val temporal: Any? = LocalDateTime.now()

when (temporal){
    is LocalDate -> println("dayOfMonth: ${temporal.dayOfMonth}")
    is LocalTime -> println("second: ${temporal.second}")
    is LocalDateTime -> println("dayOfMonth: ${temporal.dayOfMonth}, second: ${temporal.second}")
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for my needs here, because method.returnType is a Class<T>. Try it in your IDE. Thanks

Comment: @fridgepolice I just posted an snippet of the when statement, is up to you to return what you want, I put a.`println` as a demo but you can return a Class

Comment: right, but you can't differentiate between generic types over class. That's my question here. Please try the code sample so you can see what I mean.